# Python/wxPython - Windows 10 ActionCenter Notification

Tags: python, notifications, wxpython, windows-10

I have programmed a small tray application (python/wxpython) and i am now wondering how i can force its notifications to be persistent in the windows 10 ActionCenter.

The Program appears under Settings\System\Notifications i can configure it there to show its Notifications in the ActionCenter and on top of everything else.

This creates following registry key in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\Settings`:

`Microsoft.Explorer.Notification.{B50D3CA7-B170-24D3-7FC4-29B295181444}`

which stores all the relevant settings (rank, ShowInActionCenter as DWORD).

My question is now how is this "ID" generated? (`{B50D3CA7-B170-24D3-7FC4-29B295181444}`) I am deploying this application in our organisation and i want to force its notifications to be persistent. So i have to deploy or set this registry setting automatically but i dont know if this ID will be the same on all machines. 
I cant find it anywhere else in the registry and it is not the AppID i configured in the InnoSetup Installer.

Comment: So you asking `why os give a number when using cpu/ram ?`. As a service need a `clsid` if registered or not ! How to share app/service without class id ?

Comment: i dont really understand your answer/question...
im just wondering how this ID is generated as i can't find it anywhere else stored in the registry. Is there a way to generate it myself if it is influenced of the system it is running on. 
i just want to automate configuring these settings but i can't do it if i dont know how those are created.

Comment: You can't automate this if not registered by OS. You talking about `sc.exe` but i haven't more information about this. I think now "what is wrong when you update a version ?"